# I can't implement snap scrolling using tailwind

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, snap

this is my jsx code, where I am trying to implement snap scrolling, but it doesn't work, I have no idea what I did wrong:

```
<div className="w-screen flex flex-col items-center text-white snap-y overflow-scroll snap-mandatory">
  <div className=" flex items-center justify-center relative h-screen snap-start">
    <Hello />
  </div>
  <div className="w-[80%] flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-[50px] h-screen gap-[100px] snap-start">
    <Technologies />
  </div>
  <div className="w-[80%] flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-[50px] h-screen gap-[50px] snap-start">
    <Projects />
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to find out what I did wrong, there is no answers to my problem in official documents

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to implement snap scrolling using the CSS scroll-snap feature. However, there might be some issues in your code that prevent it from working as expected. Here are some common mistakes and possible solutions:

1. Use overflow-y: scroll instead of overflow-scroll for scroll-snap to work correctly.
2. Make sure the parent container (.w-screen) has sufficient height to
   allow snapping to different sections. If the parent container's
   height is smaller than the sum of its child containers' heights,
   scrolling may not work as expected.
3. Ensure that the scroll-snap-align property is set to start for each
   section that you want to snap to. In your code, you have used
   snap-start as the class name, but it should be applied as a CSS
   property.

```html
<div className="w-screen flex flex-col items-center text-white overflow-y-scroll snap-y snap-mandatory">
  <div className="flex items-center justify-center relative h-screen snap-start">
    <Hello />
  </div>
  <div className="w-[80%] flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-[50px] h-screen gap-[100px] snap-start">
    <Technologies />
  </div>
  <div className="w-[80%] flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-[50px] h-screen gap-[50px] snap-start">
    <Projects />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text really sounds like generative AI. Please note that [ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/5470544).